# Merge records and Restore Deleted records for Salesforce using HTTP or API call from Postman?

Tags: api, salesforce, integration

I am trying to see if I can make a Merge Record call or Restore Deleted Records using an API call (read REST or SOAP call). Tried researching around it but most examples need custom code written in Java or .NET.

I am trying to see if it can be done using HTTP Request itself without custom code. In worst case, Apex Web Services related calls can be written I suppose but I am trying to find a way using HTTP Request itself.

I have gone through API documentation but my doubt persists on how to implement. In Salesforce API I couldnt find a suitable call around this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP API has the merge operation. Import the WSDL to your project. Call `login` first, get the `serverUrl` and `sessionId`, then:

**Merge**

Request

```xml
POST https://{redacted}.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/52.0/{redacted} HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 882
Host: {redacted}
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D{redacted}</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:merge>
         <urn:request>
            <urn:masterRecord>
               <urn1:type>Lead</urn1:type>
               <urn1:Id>00Q3O000003aFYtUAM</urn1:Id>
            </urn:masterRecord>
            <urn:recordToMergeIds>00Q3O000003aFYuUAM</urn:recordToMergeIds>
             <urn:recordToMergeIds>00Q3O000003aFYyUAM</urn:recordToMergeIds>
         </urn:request>
      </urn:merge>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>65</current>
            <limit>5000000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mergeResponse>
         <result>
            <id>00Q3O000003aFYtUAM</id>
            <mergedRecordIds>00Q3O000003aFYuUAM</mergedRecordIds>
            <mergedRecordIds>00Q3O000003aFYyUAM</mergedRecordIds>
            <success>true</success>
         </result>
      </mergeResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Undelete** is there too.

```xml
POST https://{redacted}.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/52.0/{redacted} HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 568
Host: {redacted}
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00D{redacted}</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:undelete>
         <urn:ids>a141q000001RfNeAAK</urn:ids>
         <urn:ids>a141q000001RfOVAA0</urn:ids>
      </urn:undelete>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Don't think REST API has matching operations.

Comment: Thanks, but what I  shall  I add in the second redacted area for POST Endpoint ?

Comment: login call will return a long message with some info about your user. look for `sessionId` and reuse the value in all subsequent calls, paste it into `SessionHeader/sessionId` node. And similarly, look for `serverUrl` and make all subsequent POSTs to that. That redacted bit is Org ID (go to setup -> company information, most likely starts with `00D`) but really you should pull it from login result, not try to generate it yourself)

Comment: it's bit like you login normal to SF, via browser. You start at generic test.salesforce.com / login.salesforce.com. You provide username and pass. On success it redirects you to your correct instance (serverUrl) and puts a cookie with sessionId. And from now onwards all your next interactions are on new url, right?

Comment: Thank you so much, you were really helpful. Undelete worked for me. Now I am trying the merge call.

Comment: Can you help me around merge call ? 
The link that you shared is not helping me much, I am getting '<faultstring>No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}merge</faultstring>' error

Comment: <faultstring>Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope invalid at this location</faultstring>

New error

Comment: Looks like you cut too much out of the optional elements. Do you have to work with raw xml, can't you "consume" the wsdl, generate code in java/php/c#/whatever you use out of it? Would save you time escaping special characters etc... anyway - check the merge example out, post yours if you're still stuck?

Comment: actually I am using this soap for making a http integration map for the product that my team is working up on. So we want to actually make native soap call than the java, C# or php. So for that I am trying a raw call in postman. If it works there, I can make it work in our product map.

Comment: Wow you are amazing. You added call for merge too. So so much thanks eyescream. 